# raw files don't contain EXIF but their JPEG do (Fujifilm X100S)

Tags: raw, metadata

for many years I shoot with my Fujifilm X100S in both RAW+JPEG format. I just noticed that the RAW files don't contain any EXIF data, but their JPEG counterparties. (Don't know why, I should check the camera settings).

I'm wondering if there is a way to copy those info into the RAW files, since I may need to delete the JPEG files, and I would loose the infos.

It's a lot of files, so of course a manual method would not be ok.

The only thing that bonds the RAW and the JPEG files is the filename and the creation date, at the moment.

thank you

Comment: How are you sure the raw files actually do not contain EXIF info, or (more likely) that your raw reader/convertor doesn't bother to read it? Or are you converting the raw files and the exported files do not contain the EXIF info? (In which case you need to change your export settings to include EXIF info in the exported files.)

Comment: Two humble recommendations: From what I read it is not wise to change the RAW file, if you can better convert meta info to XMP. And disk space is so cheep, thing twice before delete anything.

Comment: How are you determining that the raw file doesn't have any meta data? The embedded JPEG file in the raw file should have the pertinent EXIF data.

Comment: Fujifilm сameras use a non-standard way of storing metadata. RAF files have one (sometimes several) large JPEG preview inside. And camera writes EXIF in the JPEG preview instead of using their own tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to have a raw file without any exif data. Besides things like camera make/model/settings, the exif contains the information required to convert the raw data into a viewable image.

Either you do not have the right program/method for viewing the exif, or it is being stripped out by a program/process.

However, there are programs that can sync XMP/IPTC data between jpegs and raw files with the same names. [Photo Mechanic](https://home.camerabits.com/) can do it with it's contact sheet function. And there is a much cheaper program called [Syncomatic](https://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/jbeardsworth/syncomatic/) that seems designed for just this purpose (I have no experience with it though).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Most RAW file formats are based on the TIFF format, which means they are one big EXIF block with one of the directories containing the actual image data.  You do not want to try and copy the EXIF data from the jpeg to the RAW.  You will most likely render the image unviewable.